Gzip binary blob data from Firebase - convert in Python
I am using the Python client to query Firestore data, and the data is stored in a Gzip (compressed) format. I am not sure what the encoding is, but using Pako ungzip in Typescript and Base64 decoding solves it.
However, in Python, Gzip uncompress and Base64 do not appear to work as the blob contains non ASCII characters:
ValueError:

 

    string argument should contain only ASCII characters


When I try to decompress straight away, I get:
TypeError: a bytes-like object is required, not 'str'

Any ideas on what to do with this blob?
'\x1f\x8b\x08\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x03í]ënã¸\x15~\x15Á»?Ú\x99\x08ã[.\x1e\xa0h3±\x07Hw\'³Hf[\x14\x83\xa0P,:QÇ\x96\\IÎL°ð\x8f¾BÑÿ\x0bô\x19ú`û\x08%©\x8b)ÞDÉ\x12M\'þ³\x93\x15Iëè\x9cÃ\x8f\x87ç\x1c\x1eþÒ\x89\x9d»9\x88:o?ÿÒñ\x9d\x05è¼Íþí¼\x0b\x82/\x9e\x7f\x1fu\x8e:^t³\x04SÏ\x99wÞÎ\x9cy\x04ÖG\x9di0_-|r`ç·_ÿóïëà«u9\x86C\\/ZÎ\x9d§+¢\tD |tb/ð\x93.ñÓ\x12¿\x0f¾Å\x85}¢8\x84¯ëÀß~ð\\\x17øé»ÐÛ\x7f\x86#1\x053oJ<þ)\x0cb0\x8d\x81\x9b?Kßú>\x08\x17«¹Cüø=\x88íG\'ôÐ×ÂW§\x14\x7fë¬×G9ýß\x87Á×Kß\x05ßXÚüÕâ\x0e\x84$mq¸\x12ÐÀ%\x97xÍMì\x84ñ\'o\x01\x18.á\x16kìÄ m¦¨pa\x8b\x1d£¦v\x984\x83O\x9cØÞ¼æ¨óèÌW@\x85\x8fG\x98º÷ø\x17\x88þÓÀ\x8fbÇ\x8f7?Õ\x89\x1e\x820F\x03Ð+T\x06|õâ\x87`\x15Û\x11\x80\x8dn\x04eFpsâ»\\^Âç\x07NVâd2ÿDü¼Á\xad\x16b+\x9f¥MLß\x19ÃÈ\x18|\x8bí\x18, %1~iö§ô;±XC\x00{NÁ\x02øq\x02SK\'\x8eAèW\x1bJôv\x96Ëù\x93\x9d\x00\x9f\x9dH¸\x93\x01aA\x13y¢N»qúC!Ü\x92røäÅs\x96ÿÙSÓ@s\x0c¢iè-\x11ª34_Á7EÖ\x1bk\x0cbÇ\x9bG\x06Rÿc0u¸¤_\x07ÁÂÌUj²\x80¼dá.}JQ\x0bÐcÛqÝ\x10DÑ6D\x17ôs\x01à¬Y,9:ºii\x03pÉµÚ\x8bÞ;\x8fAè¡V\x9a\x8eËÈÊ\x1bÿÈÒr\x17\x04sàø\x88\x12úÕ¢U\x9dxs\x08æ\x7f_ÁAÌ[Ñ/Y×`\x9e)\x14õVlhÙ!\x98¡&ô÷UÑÜBÃ¹¶VÃ\x88:\x83ÿØÐÒ\x81¯\x82ÿ\x8d(íK©D\r)\x99\x8a$.Càzp2\x81\x8bÀG\xa0\x9d2\x05bäô\x01 eÎ;\x14ðw±tB`cÀD¿<\x07³¸\x1c8±®Ãw\x06K\x10:q\x10"EÿçÊÁ\x08\x13z÷\x0fª?\x81\x1eð\x88]\x17ÖE$lÜ\x81+ð´EËb\x88\x96o\x86èp£qiCé×ç*¼V]«Ò¯\x14¼¹À.dt\x8d\x13>1\x1cCmÖ¦±\x1d£\x8cå\x9b\x13EÞ½\x9f#+R\x93äQf\x1b|î@¤/aÁÆl_ßÞ\x1eA\x10q\x9f(ÑØ\x88§6üI\x00UÝÆ\x928ê$\x02A¿Ï!\x8c\x8f÷cÌÐ]\x1b\x97ó\x00)ð\x9aÞ¸\x88D\x9bì]\x10\x7fÌ\x14ðMË\x02¾© à\x9bV\x05ÜÔ¶J$él\x0b`¦\x9c\'¥rÎíî\x1aR\x9eT\x90òÄ|)c\x95·!CøÓ9mÙrmkjS\x17Ù[lë¢ÚÛ:\nõÔÖËÂ\xa0\x84åíï>«\x12I\x0c¡÷\xa0ÈB\x08á\x16\x88¿/Ê\x8c\\ëÃj\x1e{KÞ¾Ô\tCL\t4Á\x17¤\x8dYf\x05£ßç\x9b\x98\x8d\x9bÁs(\x8eÌÒ\xadj\t\x8bÉÔj\tçÛ×\xad\x8cáÄo\x9bíwULâL=n\x10\x10ÈU\x04uá)H}E0f;ôÂ\x95\x00÷F=¬\x1f\x83àË\x8au\x07p:ìÝ6)×rå\xadRþÕ\x8aû%ov\r\x96À\x89/§\x1c7\x14Õ¨\x85}ÞÌ\x8e\x1f\x80o\x03Ø\x9e|\x83ëa²·UÔäSTÕ\x94³:"ï\x0cò\x85á68°¸@r\x06@¥þ\x17z\x9f\x83°Þ\x87Ì\x7f,:Ç\x96ñS\x87Ñi¼vól¢\x14Ø6Q¬\x16}²M\x19M\x9e\x15¿µÂúvS\\Û É\x98£6k\x92Þ\x15,%ú\x9bÔ\tãÀRÅ\x99\x9d\r¬@®W\x9b\\\n\x02ÔH-\x0c¢\x8d;R\x85\x7fô¢Øºx\x08¼)ëß\x12÷««ð\x89{u+÷w\n",\xadéc±¯wGþú\x84²O\x88,>ÑVÚf\\\xa0Áw\x13\x02oÀ<ùY\x9e\' ý\x06¢Ï³\x0cµ.\xa0µ¶Z\x14\x17\x8b+\x9c\x14ðW\x00¾D\x0ck\x926+k4M¶\tycçIHyÚf\x1aáÈ\x83\x8c\x17h¾o9kzÖ:Ø\x90ó\x071\x8cgæ`Fr=?\x076rØØï\x8e\x8e\x07}g4íOÏÎîfNw6\x05àô\x0cþïñÙ°ï\x9e\x88P\x1f³¹ÇgrCAÒÄ\x1cè÷¤$ôu\x90Ð\x97\x920ÐAÂ@JÂP\x07\tC)\tÇ:H8\x96\x92p¢\x83\x04ù\x8c8ÕAÂ©\x94\x843\x1d$t\x19\x12þ\x1cx>H\x92Ö\x0c\\xI\x06\x8d¤ì\x1bµÊ¾\x02z²Ld\x9a5Q"ÇØ\x1e\x07ç·\x97¨\x88\x169Øö8\x80ß\x1e-rÔíq\x90¿=ZäðÛã,\x01íÑ"Çá\x1eg-h\x8f\x96\x12\x13\x85³(´G\x8b\x1c\x99{\x9cÕ¡=ZÎä´p\x96\x89öh\x91Cn\x8f\x83¹\xadÑÂYº\x98fm´\x94Ø¶:q·ÄÈíëÄÝ\x12k·¯\x13wKÌÞ¾NÜ-±\x7fû:q·Ä\x10îëÄÝ\x12\x8b¸¯\x13wûrÜíëÄÝ¾\x1cwû:qw ÇÝ\x81NÜ\x1dÈqw\xa0\x13w\x07%Î\x05\x9d¸;\x90ãî@\'î\x0eä¸;Ð\x89»\x039î\x0etâî@\x8e»\x03\x9d¸;\x90ãî@\'î\x0eä¸;Ð\x89»\x039î\x0etâîP\x8e»C\x9d¸;\x94ãîP\'î\x0eå¸;Ô\x89»Ã\x12ï®NÜ\x1dÊqw¨\x13w\x87rÜ\x1dêÄÝ¡\x1cw\x87:qw(ÇÝ¡NÜ\x1dÊqwØ6î\x12I¼E*ÄÙ½ìqø-Þ\x8fÓìdY\x1d\x85\x9c+ñ\x01»Ú)Çø%²j\x07\x86å\x1e\x97Ó«5ÿ\x94(û°U\x06ê\x14\x9c9`ä:Çw§S÷d:pgýQ\x7ft<\x1c8#g6ê»\x9d\ni©¶ÅÔR`sùì²z\x0b&%ò\x856}\x84¡B\x16_ýd9â\x80´ZæÙ&\x1bY=9nËÃ\x19\x95NÝ\x13§¼\x98´¸\x1cte\x80¬\x0e<Y¬\t=¿ÀïG¿\x86Ä¦\x924@\x04ï\x89 :\x11Ì&\x82ÊDp\x97\x08²\x12ÁN:>Ç\x84É\x98h\x15\x132bâ6Lð\x84\x89`0a\x04Æ\x97Ï8Ô\x19¯6ãZfü»\x8c\x93\x95ñt2îFÆçÇ8Þ\x18ï\x17ã\x82bü@\x8c3\x86ñ\x880n\tÆ7ÀlÐ\x99]2³Ueö\x8bÌ¦\x8dÙ91Û\x17f\x0fÁ\x18ò\x8c5Í\x98´\x8c]É\x18w\x8c\x85E\x999·ÍØ\x13øXv\x96\x8fH¬\x03ÄyEÎ9nù\x80Ý\x9d[\x98ya\x14wD\x87\x16|<"\x01 Õã\x0c\x18\x92p\x99#\x19(w×Ê\'\x1eH^YI\x9d\x18Ág\x14\x16j!ÛopY\x1be)eÝ\x0f2*[örS§\x82\x94P\x06¹õÚâ\x17¥¡\x1a\r6\x9f<\x8b>ÉPÁ|Úqò¾ª\x19¥ý¬\x064\x9fn\x8f:\x11´ÁãÜNÊwjÈðÇMp_ð¶{\x84ö\x8cPý\x9ck¼Ûéuñ¾çr|ÁÙE\x1c%ek>~õA\x18e\x1d>ßn\x94\x92È¥Z$¢,l\x82Ð)\x835·BÝ÷n0]¡\x11j\x95}\x14ªÁÄÁ\x12j°ä·¤£\x01¿j\x8fâhtN\x1dÿY÷\x07\\áÎ\x07µä\x99¾%élX\x04\x15ià\tSx\x9cRRl0;¯È©6hl\x01\'Me\x06És\x88\x82s\x99m;¹Ð{.\x9c¥3õbÖê¢[\x1bw1\x95\'\x9a\'ï°gÞ7|p¥J®9|û\x02¾ä|\x06aù§À+9\x88Ø\x85CîÃ`µ¼\x01K\'u\x8fHºc\x00#Uf\x9a²IdÁflÔm±Ö[\x8b3jßZßYK\x10 \x0fcí¥ù»í\x8e\x01\x12úWá\x0c`>\x8av!à\x86Ø{²®\x1dÿ\x9e\x9dxLó\x9e\x9fç-ò¢àûó"û>\x846\x0c\x9c^AhcO\xa0\x1d\x07\x1d\x95c¾½n·Ê\x19_Øý5¡Fü£¾»âÁ\x1cDQe\x06ô«}¿Ýï\x96~?g\\¿k\x8fFù@Ö\x85z¹p8*\\h¢Ô×C\x8fíUèírqÝY]ÀóGhË!Ò,Ì£O\x1bT,\x12!îg0dwmz\x0f¤eûT4äÔ\x10\x9a\x1cCãó\x15øj]d#xõË6\x1bdìhàÆ\x99\n¶±Ò\x81g\x03\x0fÁ5[:XÂ<öÄð\x81Ç\x8dð8óàÈÕ8ëe0¶l\x11×ª\x1f8* \x81b\rÌÍ\x10&tDW\x06!¢Ô%5D\x0eñlÓâÙ¢\x05z«àö\x85ã[è\x13\xad×Vº8\x91+¿J\\\x9b[`s¿jpF¥µ\x19É9V£<#z©jyÆÈüò\x8c\x9cJ\x9bûT\x8a\x13¨\x95\\å\x19\x04u\x84\x0f*\x08\x1f\x98/|iÈR\x1e\x9eÜ¥ÐÝ¶ç¸[AÌ®¡\x95\x94ù\x11S±\x88Ó>Öï _\\k\x16XV\x14f\x95wÒ\x85ó÷f\x1byn}#\x8f\x1eªnäQ³¤z4\x9bkè%ic¸\x1b4Ffso\x8a*c\x81é\x17ñ\x9e_y\x98Á\x12ô¶I@Û©\x0b\xa0ý4´æw\x13<m\x91n*J\x06T¬¾Zb\x8d\x1bR\x80Õ\x9c=\x83â\x04ßj\x0b!JlUÙ<|\n\\\x8e\x15\x91=5È|\x88\tó!J$\x9a\x88"\x9bX?¤\n\x9c_5SÇ\x86\x88+Ø\x10±¡6\x04V9~²*Ñbð\x82\x12Ú[\x18\x05õ3\x9a5.(õ-\x97lf*&äàÞÜe\x04Ã\x91|á\xa0»\x1cÜPæ,)ãFV\x8d\x0c\x0cTV\x8a+Ø\x81tP2:Ãé\xa0ký\x80¼]MáO\x07ö\x02àÌ\x8d;¤\x98\x04o\x16\x9eï-V\x0b¾ô%¼Ù¨\x7f\x96PY\x94oa\x05*ýÙÜ\x0eÀN\x8ds\x86ñÉ¯À7}\x01OE\x00y\x04a\x8c>/ÞT\x84ý\x81æiÃTH\x85\x9f8\x97>úsÖv\x90v5Ô\xa0\x10Yâ\x94Bï·EÑ\x88óé\nÛã\x94Äñ3\x83Dëk±\x15ý\n\x92õ\x8d°\x15\x9b\x8d;b\x90\x84²/ñnP=\x0c¶;=Û\x7fæ\x8e\x0cúû*82ð\x1cWô`À¾Ü@(R\x05y\x00\x94êq°8\x8d°8[\t|vmüc\x9bßNTLÅ\x14Ý\x8cùÙ\x8f½¹JJ\x15ÓÑ`\x1cúí×_ÿKðe\x85IÿS}h¢\x87Vq_Jl9Uw¦ð\'h\x8cðf\x16-0Q\x98KÚÕ\x98äYäãË\r\x8fbþ§\x1fÄvrÍLµKFH|¬xáÍÿ,ë\x03\x001\n\x17]ú\x16üÆûìîçÚ©±ð+8ô7ûÝr\x05ªÂ\x81Â¬ræs\x0b;GD\x9f_\x06\x85\x14¢\x14\x11\nr÷\x1fP\x83\x02ö2èTM[¹B\x81$à\x9cy3~Ôæ;ÏW®\x17¼ù\x8bç\x82\x00;º¡ÍìOy\x11LIÇæé£\x0f¢¥\x87\x89ò\x13hýn·{Ü;î\x8dzôQ´>ÿ(Zf©©\x9eE\x83º\x1b¬Â)P?Â¤é ÐGÿ.pB\x17\x03\x027§\x1b\x85¢\x0eyÝ"uOí3\x01ïèV\x03YG\x80ê\x07à¯X\x8b\x9ci7íÄ\\b(K®P2ê\x06%öHl\x8e\x0b9\x1aõF\'\'\'Ãaït@¡Ñ@\x1dpzÖß\x80\x13Z³\x10Ùêi¼À(àá\x06§øq©\x86ÜHÆ\x05éÆÜÜ\xad§\x8f3t1TËëôî \x13~¡Å\x1a&ø»?\x04I9\x84Ö\r\x00´\x88[¼)BÌÁ~ÿ¬Ûí\x1f\x8fè9x2¬²ì\x97mâw9\x05\x15jj\t\x17\x83v\x0eOSøÀÞ?\x96=m\x03!\x8c\x98\x1dI½;q\x80\x8dmßEòÎ3MÔ)\x9d\x10[9»\nE,\x94\x93ú¹\x05êÈ\x96í§BË\x97$\x93Á³jñÉÜ\x9b£rUòÄw¹¼ÊÓàE÷L·\x16¥Ú9\x17á§Wãáµó\x95\x9f4\x94?o\x19xsÅæ\x98\x08Í*½\x81\x16b³¡¹t>p\x18¹\x99)\x076\x96²\x91Í\x94\x90\x9d©<ðT\x99§2¼>°³\x1a;\x91Ý-³\x16P»pÖW5Û÷úh/¥z\x15¬\x91l\x10\x8eX\x95,cü\x82xïWóyR\x0eOh\x8bh¬K¨Ó\x10A\x0eä\x8c\x89\x8a¦È\x18DÓÐ[r7Ac\x10Ãýwd½±®àÇG/\x8d\x9bEÖ¨0SRÚ";püÂxH\x94®V2\x8c³ªh\x1b>\tÊ¦½4Fr>\\i·\x96\x167¤Ö~ôTÈAìu³\x1d×ÍbÖÏ\x8a\x91\x19GT¸\x97W\x82\x15T\x90HÆ\x08\x19Y;\x87JT\x84±éÔ©\x9d\x0b\x83`°Òb¥õ8vKG¯é\x9dÎK=\x7f\x9dîè¤e4Ú\x15çÎÕ¿\x9eûMZ\x89â\x99s¬²«Í\x8b®ù×Ú\x10\râÈÂ³\x02Ûü{Õ\x96¾\x92p\x7f1O¬µØ¿±|L?Y\x9d\x97üH\x1b\x87\x99\x8d\x9b\x13ÚS²w.¢ÂuV*"*ÞiÀ®FtóNc\x1b{pÕAa\'Ì£^Â}aY=A/\x83ÓËwã{£\x95UÑ\x18)\x0e£3ÆóæÄ·$\x10MÒx\x98\x1d\nv\x1f¿\x06gé\\¹\x9cY7Ö;\x00\x99\x01\x072\x82\xa0[[(èÞJqë\x96ÏÝ®×Ü¢Ðñ\x83\x83\x86qªA7J\x0c3±\x943é{Â\x94y®þ\tÔd"U\x93ÉAMÌR\x13\x84¡\x1a\x95\x04_\x9f \x82\x92MãAE\x04*\x92\x95Ø\x7fî`\x92¨\x82\x00K6\x8d\x07=1KOô¡\x897³&Ö\x9dÈ2¡[_²\x9elbÜ&¬7\x9a\x91d"5K&\x07³ÄD\x1dÑ\x8c""\x9b\x84j<è\x07O?^\x80ABè\x01\x8b"TãAI\x0cR\x12Í8âE"\x10I[öE9D2.f$nun\x82ï^Õ"+ùÅ\x0côým²¾\x06û\x82¿Ûæú¦úWì!~%Ñ%`ýÁê)OYz\\\x85ÒGõë35[Ã\x99¸\xad\x1aÅÕà\x94Ç«\x02£Râ~ZàA!«ä¼4«¤èø]ß\x1e}î¼«3è¢tPq#\x87\x07\x8dUÞDXöuR^Î_½{uñ\n\x9déb9xçùNødCeBÎý\x19z!ì\x11{K\\<\x87\x82Òö:óÓdÎñlà@0Ûõ\x1d\x86[µ¾\x17\x15ú\x8e\x93\x13o{{\x17k\x1e¥\x96LíD¹\x14ævÞqÏ&w¶í©2·3+Xq\x96\x16¶WxÌ¤Ê\x98ú\x13{üjr\x98ØÄdUí;y\x01\x13\x9b\x17o\x16õÚ³)½Íz=Q]¯é¥·]$Àûª-Öw³\x81À\\Ô¨j\x0e¼\\\x84IÒëðæ\x91Á\x95b\x9bbþ]´Ù)7\t3\x0bg))j*ÏV\x99\xad|\x8c\x8c\x17¢\x0c¼¬Cé¯æçN:j\x89tìv\x93Ý¾\x17Û÷\x07³\x85¶¤"|\x8bö\x99\x8a@Î_ôjaíëw¯/TqÖq]% äöÓ\x8e\x81Ï\x0b«.Va\x08Eøæý*^Áå\x1b§\x10[ì\x9c\x12ô2¦8«i¡xY\x04M±\x88½È-\x9a\x14\\\x15zB\x05\'M\x9dâuw*\x17\x0cQBß\x93û\x86¼mî\x1bÚ¡_±ýÛ\x86D\x93XÑ[Ë\x1dÍ©ú,É\x1d%[¹÷L\x18\x1b\x1dyN\x00Òp\x0c,ó\x01ñ.\x13a\x9a\x0fò®\x97»e\x90ÈÉÝ>OælûK\x16z½$\x1b\x83Ä\x8d|.¾+\x9fãt\x87\x83Àk$D\x18$sò¬\xa0d¦\x0b»íÏ\x86Û«é$- \\MgäönÈFö¾û¼\x9fEuX\x85\x9a+\x86,Q¯=ÓÛ\ré\x8a\x8aË@õAs\x8dÑÜË\x88¹=\x89©VLwØ\x1f}\x15,\x15\x8azË\x9f¯5ý\x92[y%_¼Þ²\x1eDÁÕ_Eå\x15t2Ø\x8f´£d:Î,W3>\x99\x81{\x98Nw\x83ªiÒ\x85\x15©sà¼./£*È%|\x83õÚÊJR\x8ace·\x9c;\x12Ø* \x85\x9bJN\x86\x83a·w:¢/Iè\x8dÔïH@¼U¿\x1a!¡*«¢^\x14r±Í\x8cû^\x88;\x05ô\\ê\x90\x86D©K\x9c\x92\x87mÞ×À/y\x9a=móÍW\t÷\x98oÎ\x1e7nî¨\x951dßÜXýBò\x8e·\x87 \x0e\x18\x02²§m\\8eÄ5\x19(Z\x7fîºVV\x91\x90\x8då\x93\xadmÔÑÚþî§\x0cø6wÎ\x9c\x1e\x0f\x87§½ÁÙ\t\r§Ç¼[è6PÇ\x87ÚÛõÿ\x01à\x92ù\x8fÁó\x00\x00'

Tried decompressing and converting from Base64. Interestingly, ChatGPT was able to decode some of these using the following code block:
import gzip
import binascii

# Convert the hex string to binary data
hex_string = "\\x1f\\x8b\\x08\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x00\\x03\\xed\\x5b\\xd9r\\xf2:\\x12~\\x15\\xca\\x75.\\xe3\\t\\xd9\\x97\\x8b\\x99\\xe2\\x0f\\x84\\x90\\xb0\\x07\\x08\\xc9\\xa9\\\\\\x08[\\x06\\x05o\\xc82\\xdb)^bj\\xee\\xe7\\x15\\xcf#\\x1c\\xc9\\x0b1\\xd8\\x06\\x91@\\x02\\xf9\\xb9J\\xca\\x68\\xe9nu\\x7f\\xfd\\xb5\\xda\\xfeK \\xa0\\xa5BK\\xb8\\xfe\\xf3/A\\x07\\x1a\\x14\\xae\\xfd\\xbf\\xf4\\x0fA}(:\\x03\\xc4^\\x85\\xfcR\\x9eNr'\\xe3V\\xe5\\xf9^>m\\x9d\\x18\\xb7\\xc2\\x81\\x80\\xacG\\x13J\\x08\\xa8\\xc2\\xb5\\x02T\\x0bN\\x0e\\x04\\xc9PmM\\x0f\\xae(\\xfc\\x81\\x8dAN\\x97\\xe1\\x90\\xce #\\xd3\\xd9\\xa4\\x8bt\\x99\\xfe\\x64\\x11\\x8c\\xf4\\xb6@\\xc7u\\x90,C]\\xb8&\\xd8\\x86l\\xa236\\x08\\x94\\x08\\x94\\xbd\\xa5\\xd9\\xb3\\xba\\x05\\xb1\\xb3\\xa1\\x82\\xa4\\xc2\\xe3*\\x04rIWG\\xfe\\x64\\x05\\x1bZ\\xd1\\x91\\xbe\\xc6\\x84w\\x1fO\\x0ef\\xe5ISadd\\x99*\\x18\\x15\\xdd\\xc7\\x7f\\xff\\x7f\\xffMT\\x8dA\\xc2\\xf9\\x8d[\\xd0\\x18\\xa1\\xc2\\xf2\\xc7\\x8a\\x15\\xbbU\\xd4*\\x9e\\x0e\\x8e\\xcc\\x0b\\xd6\\xf4\\xa5\\xf4f\\xcdj\\x9a\\xd1\\x00R\\xc3:B\\xf6X\\x04\\xb2\\x8c\\xa1e\\xb1\\xfd\\xbdY\\xb7\\x06\\xd6l\\x15\\x04F\\xb6!\\x11\\xfb\\x00#g\\xcf\\xa9L\\xc3%2\\xfb\\xdb\\xc6\\xd8\\xec\\x63\\xba\\x94;\\x061\\xc2\\xba \\r\\xb4\\xa1hc\\xb4\\x01=\\xfc-W\\xd5\\xc3w?d\\xdd\\x82\\xbe\\x81\\x11[z^\\x9d\\x9c\\x95\\x98\\xfe\\xf8\\x9f\\xb0Z-\\xc3P!\\xd0]\\x01gw\\x8f\\x0f\\x9ch\\x81^\\x0f\\x04\\xab\\x03!\\xf1...

# Remove escape sequences
hex_string = hex_string.replace("\\x", "")

# Convert hex string to bytes
compressed_data = binascii.unhexlify(hex_string)

# Decompress the gzipped data
decompressed_data = gzip.decompress(compressed_data)

# Convert bytes to string
decoded_string = decompressed_data.decode('utf-8')

decoded_string

However, the original hex_string is not what I prompted so there is some conversion taking place.

Are you sending a request with an Accept-Encoding: gzip header by any chance?

To Firestore? No I am not. I am using the google.cloud.firestore library and filtering the collection without any additional parameters like so: [db.collection("xxxx-xx-xx-data").where('__name__', "in",[app_id]).get()[0].to_dict()

That is raw gzipped data, that has been destroyed by being interpreted as Unicode text.  You need to somehow get it out of the database as a bytes or bytearray object - I'm not familiar with the tools you're using, so can't be any more specific.  (Base64 is not involved here at all.)

I can't get it out of the database in another format as it's part of a larger json payload with keys and values that are plain text and non compressed. How do we know it's been destroyed by being interpreted as unicode?

ChatGPT was able to decode a few of these using the code block I posted but I don't know how they got to the "hex string" from the original prompt

your blob doesn't look like base64 but like normal raw data. How did you get it? Maybe in some place you shouldn't convert it to string. OR maybe you should decode and encode it with unicode_escape and raw_unicode_escape instead of utf-8

"\\x1f\\x8b\\x08\\x00".encode('raw_unicode_escape').decode('unicode_escape').encode('raw_unicode_escape') - and it gives bytes which you can write to file to get gzip file

or with single \  you may need "\x1f\x8b\x08\x00".encode('raw_unicode_escape') - and it gives bytes which you can write to file to get gzip file
